# 2d Unity Shooting Bug Where The Player Shoots More Than The Cap Should Allow

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This Unity C# 2D Player Controller script has it so the player character is able to shoot twice before they have to be on the ground to reload and shoot again. The problem is that the player can shoot once, wait a few moments, and then shoot three times in a row when the cap should be two times and then they need to reload before they can shoot again. Any insight or help will be much appreciated.

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool enableDebugLogs = false;
    public bool isGrounded;
    public bool isReloading;
    public bool isPlayingWindSound;
    public bool isFalling;
    public bool canMoveFreely;

    public float recoilForce = 10.0f;
    public float moveSpeed = 5.0f;
    public float maxSpeed = 10.0f;
    public float windSoundDelay = 1.0f;
    public float shotCooldown = 0.1f;
    public float timeFalling = 0.0f;
    public float groundedTime = 0.0f;
    public float groundedDuration = 0.2f;
    public float freeMoveDuration = 1.0f;
    public float idleTimeThreshold = 1.0f;
    public float reloadTime = 0.1f;

    public Camera mainCamera;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public Vector2 groundCheckSize;
    public LayerMask groundLayer;
    public int maxShotsBeforeReload = 2;
    public int shotsFired;

    public AudioClip shootSound;
    public AudioClip windSound;
    public AudioSource audioSource;
    public AudioSource windAudioSource;
    public Texture2D crosshairTexture;
    private Vector3 savedPosition;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
    private Animator animator;

    private float lastShotTime;
    private float lastMouseMovementTime;
    private PlatformMovement currentPlatform;

    public void Initialize(int shotsFired, bool isReloading)
    {
        this.shotsFired = shotsFired;
        this.isReloading = isReloading;
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapBox(groundCheck.position, groundCheckSize, 0, groundLayer);

        if (rb.velocity.y < 0)
        {
            timeFalling += Time.fixedDeltaTime;

            if (timeFalling >= windSoundDelay && !isPlayingWindSound && !isFalling)
            {
                isFalling = true;
                animator.SetBool("IsFalling", isFalling);
                Debug.Log("IsFalling set to true");

                if (!windAudioSource.isPlaying)
                {
                    windAudioSource.clip = windSound;
                    windAudioSource.Play();
                    isPlayingWindSound = true;
                }
            }

            if (isPlayingWindSound)
            {
                float volumeFactor = Mathf.Clamp(timeFalling / 10.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
                windAudioSource.volume = volumeFactor;
            }
        }
        else if (isGrounded)
        {
            timeFalling = 0.0f;

            if (isFalling)
            {
                isFalling = false;
                animator.SetBool("IsFalling", isFalling);
                animator.SetBool("IsLayingDown", true);
            }

            if (isPlayingWindSound)
            {
                StartCoroutine(FadeOutWindSound(0.2f));
            }
        }
        if (shotsFired >= maxShotsBeforeReload && !isReloading && isGrounded)
        {
            isReloading = true;
            StartCoroutine(Reload());
        }

        if (isGrounded)
        {
            groundedTime += Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        }
        else
        {
            groundedTime = 0.0f;
        }

        Vector2 mousePosition = mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        Vector2 shotDirection = (mousePosition - (Vector2)transform.position).normalized;
        float facingDirection = 1.0f;
        if (spriteRenderer.flipX)
        {
            facingDirection = -1.0f;
        }
        animator.SetFloat("LookHorizontal", shotDirection.x * facingDirection);
        animator.SetFloat("LookVertical", shotDirection.y);
        if (animator.GetBool("IsLayingDown") == false)
        {
            if (shotDirection.x > 0)
            {
                spriteRenderer.flipX = false;
            }
            else if (shotDirection.x < 0)
            {
                spriteRenderer.flipX = true;
            }
        }

        float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        Debug.Log("Horizontal Input: " + horizontalInput); // Debug code
        animator.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(horizontalInput));
        if (Mathf.Abs(horizontalInput) > 0 && isGrounded) // if there is any horizontal input and the player is grounded
        {
            animator.SetBool("IsLayingDown", false); // set IsLayingDown to false
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && shotsFired < maxShotsBeforeReload && !isReloading && !animator.GetBool("IsLayingDown") && Time.time - lastShotTime >= shotCooldown)
        {
            shotsFired++;
            lastShotTime = Time.time; // Update the time of the last shot

            rb.AddForce(-shotDirection * recoilForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            animator.SetBool("IsRecoiling", true);
            StartCoroutine(StopRecoilAnimation());

            audioSource.PlayOneShot(shootSound);
        }
        if ((isGrounded || canMoveFreely))
        {
            Vector2 horizontalForce = new Vector2(horizontalInput * moveSpeed, 0);
            Debug.Log("Horizontal Force: " + horizontalForce); // Debug code
            rb.AddForce(horizontalForce, ForceMode2D.Force);
        }
        if (rb.velocity.magnitude > maxSpeed)
        {
            rb.velocity = rb.velocity.normalized * maxSpeed;
        }

        animator.SetBool("IsGrounded", isGrounded);

        // Check for mouse movement
        if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") != 0 || Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") != 0)
        {
            lastMouseMovementTime = Time.time;
            animator.SetBool("MouseMoving", true);
        }
        else
        {
            animator.SetBool("MouseMoving", false);
        }

        // Check if the time since the last mouse movement exceeds the threshold
        if (Time.time - lastMouseMovementTime > idleTimeThreshold)
        {
            animator.SetBool("IsIdle", true);
        }
        else
        {
            animator.SetBool("IsIdle", false);
        }

        Debug.Log("Player Velocity: " + rb.velocity); // Debug code
    }


    private IEnumerator FadeOutWindSound(float duration)
    {
        float startVolume = windAudioSource.volume;

        float elapsedTime = 0.0f;
        while (windAudioSource.volume > 0.0f)
        {
            elapsedTime += Time.fixedDeltaTime;
            windAudioSource.volume = Mathf.Lerp(startVolume, 0.0f, elapsedTime / duration);
            yield return null;
        }

        windAudioSource.Stop();
        isPlayingWindSound = false;
    }

    public void EnableFreeMovement()
    {
        canMoveFreely = true;
        StartCoroutine(DisableFreeMovement());
    }

    private IEnumerator DisableFreeMovement()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(freeMoveDuration);
        canMoveFreely = false;
    }

    private IEnumerator Reload()
    {
        isReloading = true;
        Debug.Log("Reloading started.");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(reloadTime);
        shotsFired = 0;
        isReloading = false;
        Debug.Log("Reloading finished. Current shot count: " + shotsFired);
    }

    private IEnumerator StopRecoilAnimation()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).length);
        animator.SetBool("IsRecoiling", false);
    }
    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawWireCube(groundCheck.position, groundCheckSize);
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        PlatformMovement platformMovement = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<PlatformMovement>();
        if (platformMovement)
        {
            currentPlatform = platformMovement;
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        PlatformMovement platformMovement = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<PlatformMovement>();
        if (platformMovement && platformMovement == currentPlatform)
        {
            currentPlatform = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide what you get from debug.log ? Are you sure that you don't have maxShotsBeforeReload set in inspector?

Comment: Think you'll need to step through the code to see what's happening: https://www.google.com/search?-b-d&q=unity+step+through+code

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Overall, the logic appears to be sound, but there are several areas where it could be significantly improved. While your question pertains to technical aspects, it seems that the main issue lies in the organization of your code.

Firstly, I want to address a minor concern. Processing input inside the `FixedUpdate` function can lead to inconsistencies and imprecisions across frames. Some frames will process input, while others won't. Therefore, it is advisable to consider `Update()`. It can sometimes work just by changing that.

Here are some tips to enhance your code:

###### Clean up and simplify

Take a closer look at your code and aim to simplify it logically. Instead of using `shotsFired` and `maxShotsBeforeReload`, consider using more descriptive variable names like `magazineCount` and `magazineCap`, or even simpler options like `bulletsLeft` and `bulletsMax`. Adopting this approach will lead to more consistent logic.

###### Organize your code

Reduce complex logic by introducing methods and modifying the code within them if necessary. Logically, does it make sense to check if `shotsFired >= maxShotsBeforeReload` first? It may be more logical to check if the player has reached the maximum number of bullets right after they shoot. Otherwise, they would have to wait for another fixed update.

###### Introduce local variables

Expressions like `Time.time - lastShotTime >= shotCooldown` can be difficult to read and maintain. Consider introducing a local boolean variable like `onCooldown = (Time.time - lastShotTime <= shotCooldown)`. This will improve readability and make your code more manageable.

I hope these suggestions help you navigate through the complex structure of your code and find a suitable solution. Don't hesitate to ask further questions if needed.